# NSOutlineView indentation Problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsoutlineview

For the custom requirement, i need to handle displaying of Cell, i.e. In short in my application i subclass NSCell to ImageTextCell (standard form Apple ) and using the same to display the Cell,

When it comes to indentation, i could see, all  the element having same indentation, i.e. in my outline view i have two group and each group having more then two child element + three child element (i.e. Non Group Item ) on the top level, 
But the strange thing is all the element are displaying at the same level, do i need to set anywhere indentation level and should take care of displaying text and image as per indentation level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell drawing code is probably hardcoding `0` as the x-coordinate to draw from, rather than respecting the cell bounds passed to it. In short, you do not need to do anything special to handle indentation; we can't really help more without seeing some code.

Comment: this is what i am guessing, basically i took Apple ImageTextCell Code to draw the Cell, refer - (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView function for the code located at http://martinkahr.com/files/source/ImageTextCellSample_R836.tgz fileName ImageTextCell.m

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks its working fine, i handled the indentation in the DrawFrameRect